# Comma after "when"

Tags: word-usage, commas

Do I need a comma after "when" in the sentence:

> He was still a young man in 1843 when he wrote the story.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need a comma after "when" in the sentence. This is because when is a subordinatating conjunction that begins an adverb clause. https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/37/ is a reference for this.